How do I remove a file in FilePond?
I've started work on a React project which includes an image uploader which uses FilePond.
It's set up like this:
FilePondLib.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview)

const createImage = (image, file) =>

export default function ImageUpload({
  image,
  setImage,
  setFile,
}) {
  const fileRef = useRef(null)
  const filePondRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div>
      {image && (
        <FilePond
          ref={filePondRef}
          credits={false}
          files={[image]}
          onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
            if (fileItems.length === 0) {
              setImage(undefined)
              setFile(undefined)
            }
          }}
          v-bind:required={required}
        />
      )}
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}

This works fine and I can select an image, which then appears in the preview window.  The issue I'm having is that if I then decide not to upload the image after all, I can't see a way to cancel it.  There's an 'X' button, which, if I click it, removes the image preview and then loads it up again.
I found that there was a handler called onremovefile, so I tried to use that:
      onremovefile={(e) => {
        setImage(undefined)
        setFile(undefined)
      }}

but it appears to be triggered every time a file is uploaded, and just removes it immediately.
How do I handle this? Thanks!
